# C# PISDK - How do you pull a full column of data from a PISDK server using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, osisoft

I am looking to pull full column data from a table in a PISDK Server, and then populate any blank fields in that column with the field from another column in the same row. This would be similar to a select statement in SQL:

```
Select nvl(column1, column2)
From table1
```

if you are not familiar with SQL, this just returns column2 if column1 is null, otherwise it will return column1

My main problems are that I can get a point from the server, but I cannot get a full column and that I am not sure how to replace null column1 fields with column2.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to answer my own question. For future reference, to do this load in the PI tags as a column in a csv and then copy each row into the correct column1 of your other csv. then simply find anywhere the tag is null and pull its corresponding column2 value.